# mysql string split

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am using the following queries and getting diff results.

```
SELECT SUM(amt) FROM table1 WHERE id in (114,116) and another_id = 10;

result is 10+20 = 30

SELECT SUM(amt) FROM table1 WHERE id in (REPLACE("116,114",'"',"")) and another_id = 10;

result is 10
```

i was suggested to use a string split function and put the splits in a table,can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT SUM(amt) 
>   FROM table1 
>   WHERE id in (REPLACE("116,114",'"',"")) and another_id = 10;

It would help if we knew what you were trying to do.

At a guess, I suspect that you want to provide a facility where someone can specify a set of ids and pass that as an argument to the query.

A simple solution would be:

```
WHERE CONCAT('%,', id, ',%') LIKE ('${submitted_string}')
```

But this will not be able to use any index on table1.id

AFAIK there's no way to cast an array/string to a table type in MySQL, so you'd need to parse the string and put the values temporaril;y into a table along with a key referencing the session (or into a temporary table). Doing this in SQL is rather hard work - it's a lot simpler to use a logic tier on top - which, based on my interpretation of what your trying to achieve you must already have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears ID is a numeric field...

Try this for the second example...

```
SELECT SUM(amt) FROM table1 WHERE ","+CAST(id AS CHAR)+"," in (","+"116,114"+",") 
                             and another_id = 10;
```